# My Home Page settings don’t work In Opera; how do I fix it?

Tags: google-search, igoogle, opera

I use Opera and set my home page to **www.google.com**. I accidentally clicked on the iGoogle link and now I can’t get rid of it.

My home page in preferences is still **www.google.com** but when I load the browser, **www.google.com/ig** is displayed.

How can I revert back to the homepage I want displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scroll to the bottom of the page and click on the **Classic Home** link, in the bottom-left corner.

[image]

When you click on iGoogle, it sets a cookie so it can automatically redirect you to the iGoogle page. You can get rid of it by removing the cookies as well.